# Importing tess-two and eyes-two in Android Studio project

Tags: android-studio, tess-two

I am trying to import the tesseract android version to my project, but I’ve found a lot of troubles to import native libraries as tess-two into AS (for the non full supporting of ndk by AS for now). Fortunately this link propose a sort of workaround to import tess-two library: https://coderwall.com/p/eurvaq/tesseract-with-andoird-and-gradle

There's a solution to import also the EYES-TWO library, that has dependences from TESS-TWO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same operations of tess-two will be applied on eyes-two(creating build.gradle, ecc..), adding the dependence from tess-two and adding a directive to the aidl files on build.gradle, it will be imported correctly.